odoo 8 get data from table and insert it in another table
I want to get data from table target_product_line and store it table weekly_planning_line when I save it in draft. So made like this
class weekly_planning(models.Model):
_name='weekly.planning'

@api.multi
def action_draft(self):  
    self.state='draft'
    res = super(weekly_planning,self).action_draft()    
    weekly_planning = self.env['weekly.planning.line']
    self.env.cr.execute('''
        Select tpl.customer_id
                    FROM sale_target_detail std
                        LEFT JOIN target_product_line tpl on tpl.target_product_id = std.id
                    WHERE std.sales_id = %s
                        AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM std.target_date) = %s
                    GROUP BY tpl.customer_id
    ''',(self.user_id.id, self.year_period))
    for rec in self.env.cr.dictfetchall():
        weekly_planning.create({'weekly_planning_id':self.id,
                                  'customer_id':rec['customer_id'],
                                  })
    
    return res

No error but no customer inserted in table weekly_planning_line.
Please help. Thanks

I think i have mistaken by add the script in draft, so I decided to put the script in the confirm section and made some update, and it works
@api.multi
def action_confirm(self):      
    self.state='confirm'
    self.env.cr.execute("""
                Select tpl.customer_id
                    FROM sale_target_detail std
                        LEFT JOIN target_product_line tpl on tpl.target_product_id = std.id
                    WHERE std.sales_id = %s
                        AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM std.target_date) = %s
                    GROUP BY tpl.customer_id
                """
            ,(self.user_id.id, self.year_period))
    for x in self.env.cr.dictfetchall():
        profit_line_obj = self.env['weekly.planning.line']
        profit_line_obj.create({'weekly_planning_id':self.id,
                                'customer_id':x['customer_id'],
                                })

